# Clone/Copy a record in testSetup

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is it possible to clone/create a copy of a record in test class. I already have a record and I want to copy/clone it and then change a couple of fields data.
I'm already using factory method to create record with basic data.
So, now in record 1, I update certain fields data. In record 2, I need the updated fields data from record 1 and on top of that I want to update a few more fields so that I'm able to cover all scenarios in my actual apex controller.

Is there a way I can achieve this in test class?

Comment: Have you checked the `Sobject.clone()` method? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this compiles and creates 2 records with the same base and additional modifications:

```
@isTest
private class TestDemo {
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        List<Account> testRecords = new List<Account>();
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test A',
                                BillingCity = 'New York'); // Or use your factory class to create the account
        testRecords.add(a);
        a.Phone = '555-555-555';
        Account b = a.clone();
        b.BillingCity = 'San Diego';
        testRecords.add(b);
        insert testRecords;
    }

    @isTest
    static void myTest() {
        system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE BillingCity = 'San Diego'].size());
    }
}
```